# Why create classes to represent data in web applications?

Tags: asp.net, oop, poco

In the past, I've generally used classes to represent my data in applications I design and build.  But in web applications, that doesn't seem to be needed/applicable, because data is stored in a database, and things like `DataSet` work great for retrieving and saving data.

I currently work with ASP.NET, and the data-bound controls (such as `GridView`) seem to like to bind to `SqlDataSource`, `ObjectDataSource`, `DataView`, etc.  So, given a static `MyDB` class that pulls a `DataSet` out of the database, my data-oriented page code often essentially looks like this:

```
DataSet employeeData = MyDB.GetData();
DataView dvEmpData = new DataView(employeeData);
grdData.DataSource = dvEmpData;
grdData.DataBind();
```

Thus I don't generally have data classes to correspond to my database schema.  But new developments like [POCO](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) and the EF Framework endorse creating and using those classes.  What is the advantage of this?  My ideas are:

- Compile-time errors where misspellings would have otherwise gone unnoticed until runtime.  `employeeData[0].Rows[i]["Name"]` is not as nice as `employees[i].Name` where `employees` is an `IEnumerable<Employee>`
- In C# 3 and later, ability to use LINQ and cool extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>` to filter data collections flexibly instead of having to create/change a stored procedure or query in the database for every aggregation/selection I need to do.
- Source code is easier to keep under SCM than database stuff, which means keeping more logic in the source code is better.
- A guy like me who learned CS doing local applications is more comfortable :-)

On the other hand, converting data to .NET classes before putting them onscreen is a step that will take computational time, and is not strictly necessary.  And I've got a feeling that `GridView` and its compatriots will prefer binding to `DataView` over `IEnumerable<T>`.  Also, the database is going to be faster at querying and aggregating data than LINQ.

What is the reasoning behind the approach endorsed by POCO?  Have I covered it here, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your specific question concisely:**

Utilizing business objects allows you to execute logic on data in a memory more efficiently than in SQL or in an ad-hoc fashion in multiple locations.

- Example: Need to setup a URLRewrite when a page name changes? One central location for this is clearly ideal.

**However...**

You can rule out most negatives by using LINQ to SQL or, in more complex cases, other ORM's such as the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?ppud=4) or [nHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate).

Read [Part 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) and [Part 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx) of Scott Gu's blog on LINQ to SQL for some inspiration on the subject.

- With LINQ to SQL, you get the benefits without the drawbacks (that you mentioned), plus a few extra benefits.

**And yet...**

In situations where you don't need that sort of non-trivial logical -- you may as well use a [SQLDataSource](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-vb) and bind directly to a Gridview; however, LINQ to SQL is so simple that many prefer it even in the simplest of cases.

Comment: That looks great!  How does it handle updates to the database?  What happens if I change my update/select/delete SPROC to take more parameters, or change the schema of a table during development?  I've used TableAdapters in ASP.NET 2 and had problems with that.

Comment: To update data: Dim DB as new AppDataContext :: MyProduct.Price = NewPrice ::   DB.SubmitChanges()

Comment: LINQ to SQL automatically generates SQL by default to perform selects / updates / etc. However, you can specify overrides (such as stored procedures). I suggest spending a coups hours reading over these... you'll be glad you did!  start with Part1! http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/07/27/links-to-scott-guthrie-s-using-linq-to-sql-tutorials.aspx